# Mongodb $strcasecmp. Strange behaviour when the field content has dollar signs

Tags: mongodb, string-comparison, aggregation-framework

I'm triying to compare two strings on MongoDB Aggregation Framework. This is the query I'm using:

```
db.people.aggregate({
   $project:{
    name:1,
    balance:1,
    compareBalance:{$strcasecmp:["$balance","$2,500.00"]}
   }    
});
```

My problem is that each "$balance" field has a dollar sign at the begining of the string, and the results returned by the query seem to be incorrect. For example:

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5257e2e7834a87e7ea509665"),
   "balance" : "$1,416.00",
   "name" : "Houston Monroe",
   "compareBalance" : 1
}
```

As you can see the results, the field comparision is 1, but it should be -1 because $2,500.00 is higher than $1,416.00. In fact, all comparisions has a value of 1.

There is a workaround by using $substr to remove the dollar sign at the beginning of all fields, but I want to know who is doing this wrong, MongoDB or  me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to use the "balance" field as a numeric, for example might want to compare $10 to $100.
The best way to do this is to store the actual value, and add the formatting, the $ the , etc when displaying to the user.
So, you would have - balance: 2500

Slightly unrelated...
Not sure if you are doing much calculation on the value, but using binary floating point numbers for currency is a bad idea (can't accurately represent all numbers), so, it's often better to store an integer with the cents (or if high precision is required, an integer for hundredths  of cents)
This could give: balanceCents: 250000 or balanceFourDec: 25000000
Then you can use $gt $lt and arithmetic

Comment: Yes I agree with you. It should be a numeric field, but I only want to show on my blog how $strcasecmp works  . This info is generated with an online JSON generator. But I cannot understand the behaviour when dollar signs exists within the field value. Without dollar signs it works as expected.

Comment: There is a new operator in MongoDB 2.6 - the $literal operation http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/literal/

Comment: Many thanks. I think that operator is what I need to avoid that kind of issues. I'm currently testing with 2.4 version, but I will test it with 2.6.

Answer (score 0):

The `$` is used as a field reference operator. So, the aggregation pipeline is trying to do a comparison between a field called `"$balance"` and `"$2,500.00"`:

```
{
    "balance": "$5,000.00",
    "2,500.00": undefined
}
```

Of course, that's not what you are looking for.

You shouldn't start with the `$` in the data. Also, unless you've got fixed length strings, sorting and comparisons isn't going to work the way you would expect if you're trying to store numbers as strings. If you're just doing this as an example, I'd suggest you use the actual math operators for numbers, and leave `$strcasecmp` to actual strings.

Comment: I guessed that the problem was in dollar sign,  but MongoDB documentation does explain nothing about that. It only says something about dollar signs or dots on fields names. But it should be possible use dollar signs on fields because it is not a rare sign. I guess that is the reason for include the operator that Alan links.

Comment: While it's not documented as well as it should be, it's very clear from looking at examples that the proper way to refer to other fields in the aggregation framework is to preface the field name with a `"$"`. Further, you shouldn't be comparing numbers the way you are, and isn't a good example for a blog, or anywhere else.

Comment: Maybe you're right. I'm going to change my example to use actual strings. Anyway was interesting to find out that kind of problems. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the  { $literal: < value > } pipeline operator to ignore the cash sign.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/literal/